# Cannot save captured image to external media directory using CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I was following this code labs example [Link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4) on how to use CameraX API on Android, however when I tried to capture and save the image to the external media directory that is created in Oncreate method in the main activity I get an error message saying: Cannot save capture result to specified location

Here is the method that creates the directory, which is called in Oncreate method:

```kotlin
    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
            val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
                File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
            return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            { Log.i(TAG, mediaDir.path); mediaDir } else {  filesDir }
        }
```

from what I read in Android documentation `externalMediaDirs` creates a folder in external storage, and although my phone doesn't have external storage, the folder was successfully created at this path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.camerax/cameraX`

then this method gets called when the take picture image button gets clicked:

```kotlin
private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")


        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
            })


    }
```

However, when I click the button to capture and save the image, I get this error message:
*ImageCaptureException: "Cannot save capture result to specified location"*

What I tried:

I tried to create a folder that is local to the App and save the image there, and it worked fine, I used this method:

```kotlin
private fun takePhoto() {
.
.
.
 folder: File = File(getFilesDir(), "testFolder");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }
testImage = File(folder, "test.jpg");

val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(testImage).build()
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Im not sure what could be the problem, any help is appreciated.

**Update:**
Apparently the problem is due to a bug in CameraX API CameraX 1.0.0-beta09 along with camera-extension 1.0.0-alpha16. when using CameraX 1.0.0-beta08 along with camera-extension 1.0.0-alpha15 its working fine.

Comment: Ensure the Storage permission is granted!

Comment: `and although my phone doesn't have external storage, ` That path is on external storage. Every device has external storage. A removable micro sd card has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `resources.getString(R.string.app_name) How would we know what folder that is? Please put real names in stackoverflow posts.

Comment: Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet and check the return value.

Comment: @blackapps well, im using the exact same code that is in google codelabs, that's why I added a log to see the file path: ```Log.i(TAG, mediaDir.path)``` , also I added the pathname in my post: ```/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.camerax/cameraX```

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI I added the permission in the Manifest :       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />but still get the same error

Comment: ok so apparently is has nothing to do with permission, as permission to store in external memory is implicitly granted for Android API 19 and above. This error is due to a bug in CameraX API CameraX 1.0.0-beta09 along with camera-extension 1.0.0-alpha16. when using CameraX 1.0.0-beta08 along with camera-extension 1.0.0-alpha15 its working fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in CameraX 1.0.0-beta09. It's been patched and might be available in the next release.

It crashes because the file you're trying to save it to, isn't actually created. As a workaround use [`File.createTempFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), which creates an empty file in the directory.

```
val photoFile = File.createTempFile(
    SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()),
    ".jpg",
    outputDirectory
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Instead of createTempFile we can also use file.createNewFile(). The problem still exists in 1.0.0-rc01.