# "Wrong Offset May Cause an Infinite Loop" Error When Saving Image Using CameraX

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

Can someone please help me fix these errors I am getting. I am trying to save an image after it is captured but it's not working and keeps on giving me these errors about the tag being a ULONG and that a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop. I am not sure where the error is was I using the File class wrong? or maybe the getExternalDirectory part?

```
2020-09-22 13:52:36.684 9910-9964/com.example.cameraxapp D/CaptureSession: Opening capture session.
2020-09-22 13:52:36.757 9910-9964/com.example.cameraxapp D/CaptureSession: Attempting to send capture request onConfigured
2020-09-22 13:52:36.757 9910-9964/com.example.cameraxapp D/CaptureSession: Issuing request for session.
2020-09-22 13:52:36.769 9910-9964/com.example.cameraxapp D/CaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession.onConfigured() mState=OPENED
2020-09-22 13:52:36.769 9910-9964/com.example.cameraxapp D/CaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession.onReady() OPENED
2020-09-22 13:52:37.318 9910-9963/com.example.cameraxapp D/StreamStateObserver: Update Preview stream state to STREAMING
2020-09-22 13:52:38.546 9910-9910/com.example.cameraxapp D/ImageCapture: Send image capture request [current, pending] = [0, 1]
2020-09-22 13:52:38.555 9910-9963/com.example.cameraxapp D/CaptureSession: Issuing capture request.
2020-09-22 13:52:38.612 9910-9939/com.example.cameraxapp W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported
2020-09-22 13:52:38.852 9910-9910/com.example.cameraxapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
2020-09-22 13:52:38.852 9910-9910/com.example.cameraxapp W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since data format (ULONG) is unexpected for tag: GPSAltitudeRef
2020-09-22 13:52:38.853 9910-9910/com.example.cameraxapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
2020-09-22 13:52:38.853 9910-9910/com.example.cameraxapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
2020-09-22 13:52:38.927 9910-9946/com.example.cameraxapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd380e800: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd3842250)
```

I think it is coming from this function since it is where it deals with files.

```
//take photo function
private void takePhoto() {

    // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
    File photoFile;
    photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "IMG_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg");

    // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build();


    imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
        @Override
        public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo Capture Succeeded: "+ outputFileResults, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo capture failed: "+ error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What CameraX version are you using?

Comment: version 1.0.0-beta07

Comment: I moved it to version 1.0.0-beta10 but it crashed when I ran it so I changed it back.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64003895/7746134

Comment: I tried that solution and it said it was successful onImageSaved but I still get the same errors and there are new ones. I tried looking for the picture but I couldn't find it so I'm not sure if it is actually saving it.

Comment: Do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try saving your image using FileOutputStream:

```
imageCapture.takePicture(cameraExecutor, object:, ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo Capture Succeeded: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            val data = image.image?.toBitmap() // image capture in bitmap
            val out = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            data?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, QUALITY_PHOTO, out)
            out.close()
        }
        override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo capture failed: "+ error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

At least, that's how I did it and it worked!