# I want to create app that can take photo using cameraX but its is not saving photos

Tags: android, android-camera, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I created app with PreviewView, button and preview is working perfect but ImageCapture is not working. I set button's onClick to capture image but getting exception "Cannot save capture result to specified location". Please help me....

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/HeyThisISJayuir.jpg");

ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions =
                        new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
                imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(MainActivity.this),
                        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageSaved(ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError(ImageCaptureException error) {
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63978064/cannot-save-captured-image-to-external-media-directory-using-camerax relevant ?

Comment: I found that page before but nothing helped from that.

Answer (score 1):

have you used RunTime Permission for

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**and**

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?
this line need permission

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/HeyThisISJayuir.jpg");
```

If not please before take pic use runtime permission and grant access then take pic

Comment: I added those permissions in manifest but didnt wrote any code for permission. But I allowed permission from settings. My preview is working so I can tell permission isn't the issue.

Comment: you need android runtime permission additional adding in manifest here is a post for runtime permission https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859077/7772174

Comment: Following permissions are allowed according to phone settings:  "Camera : while using app",  "Allow management of all files".  Is there any other permissions I need?

Answer (score 1):

here is another answer
this is complete code for CameraX by Kotlin and works like charm:

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/image_capture_button"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="take_photo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/vertical_centerline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/video_capture_button"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="start_capture"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vertical_centerline" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/vertical_centerline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".50" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

main_activity :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.video.*
import androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture
import androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import android.provider.MediaStore

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.os.Build
import com.example.junk2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding

private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

private var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
private var recording: Recording? = null

private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(viewBinding.root)

    // Request camera permissions
    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        startCamera()
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
    }

    // Set up the listeners for take photo and video capture buttons
    viewBinding.imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }
    viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { captureVideo() }

    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}

private fun takePhoto() {
    // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

    // Create time stamped name and MediaStore entry.
    val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
        .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
        }
    }

    // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
        .Builder(contentResolver,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            contentValues)
        .build()

    // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
    // been taken
    imageCapture.takePicture(
        outputOptions,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun
                    onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${output.savedUri}"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        }
    )
}


private fun captureVideo() {}

private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .build()


        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)


        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}


private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    cameraExecutor.shutdown()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
    IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }
    }
}


companion object {
    private const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
    private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
    private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
        mutableListOf (
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ).apply {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
}
```

}

build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

def camerax_version = "1.1.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"

implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> > File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/HeyThisISJayuir.jpg")

Dont mess around with a camera app to create that file.

Your app can try to create one itself.

And will discover that it will not go.

Try instead:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "HeyThisISJayuir.jpg")
```

Comment: I tried this and still getting same exception.

Comment: Please give better info. `getting exception "Cannot save capture result to specified location". ` That is no exception but a complaint. Please tell what is going on.

Comment: Should I give whole code?  I described everything above. I used button and previewview and set Previewview as view holder. Previewview is working. I took whole code from documentation. But imageCapture is not working. I will give whole code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is not working android s+ devices , so use `getExternalFilesDir(null)`  method